# Dynamic projections in LINQ-to-Entities

Tags: c#, wcf, linq

Is it possible to define the code that goes into a `Select()` projection dynamically? I have a WCF service that exposes data objects resembling the following:

```
class Exam {
    string CourseName;
    DateTime Date;
    Attendee[] Attendees;
}

class Attendee {
    string Name;
    …
}
```

in methods that look like:

```
Exam[] GetExamList() {
    return _db.Exams.Select(e => new Exam {
        CourseName = e.Course.Name,
        Date = e.Date
        // Attendees stays set to null
    });
}

ExamDetail GetExamDetail(long examId) {
    return _db.Exams.Select(e => new ExamDetail {
        CourseName = e.Course.Name,
        Date = e.Date,
        Attendees = e.Attendees.Select(a => …)
    });
}
```

Basically, I'm flattening a table hierarchy into DTOs. (Of course, my actual model has a lot more attributes.)

What I'd like to do is reuse the code that does the projections for the properties `Exam` and `ExamDetail` have in common - there's quite a lot of it, most of it is used in several methods, and I'd like to avoid making a separate database roundtrip. Is there a way to specify a projection in multiple steps in LINQ-to-Entities?

Comment: Are the projections that goes into the Select methods Func<Exam, Exam>?. I mean, can you just do: 

return _db.Exams.Select(e=> CreateExam(e));?

If yes, you could ask for the type of 'e' and return the exam with the properties that you want. Is that what you want?

Comment: Have you looked into [the AutoMapper library](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)? It might help reduce the redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting thing about LINQ is that it has deffered execution so that it won't actually perform the query until you call .ToList or enumerate over the items. So you can build the first part of the query and return an IQueryable. Not sure if this answers your question but it might be helpful though.

```
public void TestDB() {
        demoEntities de = new demoEntities();
        var q = firstPart(de, d => false);
        foreach(var item in q.Where(e => e.EmployeeID == 1)){

        }
    }

    public IQueryable<Employee> firstPart(demoEntities de, Func<Department, bool> departmentFilter) {
        return from e in de.Employees
               where departmentFilter(e.Department)
               select e;
    }
```

Comment: This still requires another database hit to get the attendees but that's not too bad with just one level of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea (the code is not good) but I think this could be what you are looking for:

```
IEnumerable<Exam> GetExams() {
    return _db.Exams.Select(e => CreateExamById(e);
}

IEnumerable<Exam> GetExamWithAttendees(long examId) {
    return _db.Exams.Select(e => CreateExamById(e, examId);
}

Exam CreateExamById(Exam exam, long examId=0){
    return new Exam {
        CourseName = exam.Course.Name,
        Date = exam.Date,
        Attendees = e.Attendees.Select(a => a..... == examId ...)
    };
}
```

Comment: LINQ-to-Entities only supports expression trees, and they have to be expression trees that can be evaluated "in the database" – you can't use call arbitrary C# code in them. Flattening the inheritance hierarchy and just omitting the missing fields could be of help though.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the code you provided has some flaws in that you are returning exam from the method that should be returning examdetail, unless there is some inheritance relationship, but it seems backward in that it would probably be that an examdetail is an exam rather than exam is an examdetail.  one way or another, something like this might be along the lines of something helpful:

```
ExamDetail GetExamWithAttendees(long examId) {
return GetExams.Select(e => {var exam = e; exam.Attendees = e.Attendees.Select(a => …); return exam;});
```

}

Comment: That's a mistake in making the sample code, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Also, you can't pass a statement lambda to a LINQ-to-Entities `Select()`.